# Gradle copy/remove a file according to another filename

Tags: gradle

I have these files:

- target/my-SNAPSHOT-0.0.1.jar
- conf/my.conf

I want them to be copied to be:

- /my/install/my-SNAPSHOT-0.0.1.jar
- /my/install/my-SNAPSHOT-0.0.1.conf

I have a gradle script that looks something like this:

```
into '/my/install'

from ('target'){
  include '*.jar'
}
```

How can I change it to properly copy and rename the my.conf file based on the name of the JAR?  The name of the JAR will change and is NOT generated by a gradle script, but some entrenched Maven pom.xml external to my gradle script.